# Emotion + Gatsby Serve: theme does not load except after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, emotion

My problem seems isolated to components that combine `css` and `withTheme` from `@emotion/react` and `styled` from `@emotion/styled`. Initially many components load unstyled, but styles pop-in after browser refresh.

Each component looks like

```
components
|- AppBar
  |- AppBar.jsx // exports UnstyledAppBar functional React component
  |- styles.js // exports styles() which uses props.theme and returns css`...`
  |- index.js // exports withTheme(styled(UnstyledAppBar)`${styles}`), i.e. a styled component with theme injected
```

Further, the styles that fail to work on first load are the styles derived from the theme prop.

In other words

```
// styles.js
const styles = (props) => {
  const { theme } = props;

  return css`
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-right: ${spacingSizeMedium}; // evaluates to 24px
  `;
}
```

The `margin-left` style renders immediately but `margin-right` requires refresh.

This issue does not appear in Gatsby development mode, but occurs in Gatsby builds.

Relevant packages

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.1.5",
"gatsby-plugin-emotion": "^6.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems that you need to add some SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) to `@emotion`. Have you tried something like:

```
import { cache } from '@emotion/css'; 
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <CacheProvider value={cache}>{element}</CacheProvider>;
};
```

*Source: https://ntsim.uk/posts/how-to-add-vanilla-emotion-ssr-to-gatsby*

Comment: This definitely feels like the right direction. I haven't got it working yet, but will check back in when I do.

Comment: Sure. Keep in mind that when dealing with `wrapRootElement` (or `wrapPageElement`) you will need to change both `gatsby-ssr.js` as well as `gatsby-browser.js`